# Problem to connect mongo DB replica set from linux, single instance run ok. Using .net core mongo driver

Tags: mongodb, .net-core, replicaset

I am trying to connect an application in .net core from a linux machine to a mongo replicaset. But I am getting a timeout error.

*Unhandled exception. System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector*

The replica ips are accessible from this machine, a response is obtained by pinging.

If in linux the connection to mongo is to a single instance of the replica, it works correctly.

This same code in windows connects without problem.

Comment: are you able to telnet on 27017 from application machine?

Answer (score 0):

If you are certain IP connectivity works, most likely you have the hostnames wrong. The hostnames used in RS config must work from each client.

See https://github.com/p-mongo/mongodb-faq.